# Using 'not' inappropriately

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I read the poem '[A Roadside Stand](http://www.english-for-students.com/a-roadside-stand.html)' by Robert Frost, and I saw this line (the line which is in bold letters below), and it doesn't seem to make sense grammatically (to me). Because I think that the line should be 'To try if it will make our being expand'.

So, the first thing I want to know is that is this line grammatically correct, from a true grammatical point of view?
Second, has the writer used 'not' in this line specifically in the poem for some specific purpose/reason?

I have also heard 'not' being used in an incorrect way in normal English conversations.
For eg - "I seriously do not know nothing about this".
I know this is definitely incorrect.
So,Has the writer also used "not" in the same kind of sense as this sentence?

> The hurt to the scenery wouldn't be my complaint
>
> So much as the trusting sorrow of what is unsaid:
>
> Here far from the city we make our roadside stand
>
> And ask for some city money to feel in the hand
>
> To try **if it will not** make our being expand,

Comment: 'To see if it will (/won't) ...'. The negative is unusual, perhaps to the point of being non-standard nowadays, but poetry has laxer rules (and hence is normally considered off-topic on ELU). Here's an example from [Hedda Gabler by Ibsen {1891}](http://www.stagebeauty.net/plays/th-hedd2.html): "Will you not take a glass of cold punch, gentlemen?" ...  Judge Brack, [Looking at his watch.] "A stirrup-cup? Yes, it wouldn't come amiss." Nowadays, we'd use 'Would [any of] you like ...'.

Comment: In this poem; I read _To try if it will or will not make our being expand_

Comment: @mplungjan How would someone get the feeling that you got to read it that way? :)

Comment: @RohitShekhawat - by reading a lot of books and poems and encountering it before.

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192796/use-of-not-in-questions

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/155421/why-is-the-phrase-should-we-not-a-positive-assertion

Comment: Thanks, @mplungjan These questions provide great deeeeeetails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grammatically fine.

Idiomatically, it is now old-fashioned. as Edwin Ashworth said; but it used to be quite common to use the negative where we would use the positive in offering things:

> Won't you come this way?
>
> Wouldn't you like to sit down?

and trying things:

> Let's see if we can't fix this.

Comment: Thanks, Colin and @EdwinAshworth :) I'm now clear about the answer.